# Run script without typing sh on Android

Tags: bash, android, bash-scripting

I wanna run my script which is located in system/bin and permissions is 755.

With `sh myscript` there is no problem but `myscipt` or `./myscript` doesn't work even if the `pwd` output is `/system/bin`.

On ubuntu I just need to put in `/usr/bin` and after setting permissions, I can run it easily. I wondered that why I have to put sh in everytime I typed it.

**For example** I push the aria2 binary file to /system/bin (755) and I can easily run with typing `aria2c`. I now that this is not script but they are same thing what I tried.

**Update**

I have hashbang like `#!/bin/bash` and which sh output is `/system/bin/sh`

Comment: Is there a "hashbang" in the file? `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or something like that? Either there is no such line, or there is one but with wrong path. No idea what the correct path on adroid would be though. Get that using `which sh`.

Comment: Please look my update

Comment: Then just modify the script to have the correct path there.

Comment: You say that I need to use`#!/system/bin/bash` instead of  `#!/bin/bash` ??

Comment: Thanks this worked. I forgot modify it for Android. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have it answered: Android has different filesystem layout, and bash is at (from linux PoV non-standard location) `/system/bin`. That's why script was working on linux (Ubuntu) and not on android.

For non-native executables (e.g. bash, python etc.) to work the "hashbang" (`#!`) has to be updated to contain correct path to interpreter (`#!/system/bin/bash`).

If there is `/usr/bin/env` on android, using `#!/usr/bin/env bash` would make the script portable.